# Axiomatisation of Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, axioms

I have seen a ridiculous "proof" claiming that $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n=-1/12.$$ The starting point is a false statement that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}=1/2.$$

Since we know that  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}$ diverges, any argument based on the value of it will be invalid.

But if we look at this from a different angle, am wondering if the following makes sense:

> For any series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$, let its "mass"
>   (for lack of a better terminology at this moment) be a real number
>   $m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\right)\in\mathbb{R}$ such
>   that the following hold:
>
> 1. If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$.
> 2. If the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is obtained from the sequence $\{a_n\}$ by inserting or deleting a list (possibly infinite) of $0$'s, then
>      $m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\right)=m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\right)$.
> 3. $m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n+b_n)\right)=m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\right)+m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\right)$.
> 4. If $C$ is a real number, $m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (Ca_n)\right)=C\times m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\right)$.
> 5. If the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is obtained from the sequence $\{a_n\}$ by reordering finitely many terms, then
>      $m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\right)=m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\right)$.
> 6. $m\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\right)=1/2.$

Then will there be any contradictions among the above axioms? Can we uniquely determine the mass of any series? For example, can one prove that

$$m\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\right)=-1/12?$$

Furthermore, if we replace the sixth condition by the following:

$$m\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\right)=k,$$

where $k$ is a fixed real number, can we uniquely determine the mass of any series?

Comment: I think that you meant to write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac1{12}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks!! I have edited the typo.

Comment: See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_⋯) for the series. Note where it says that any method which is linear and stable will fail to give a consistent value to $\sum n$. Your requirements for $m$ means it's linear and stable.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur! I think you answers my question perfectly and conclusively.